# Lucene count - group by query

Tags: indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

Can Lucene counts documents after having grouped them by a NumericField?

Only counting, not loading all documents content.

Comment: Could you refine your question and provide some example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Faceting queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-faceting) may be what you are after. Specifically a range faceting query.

Answer (score 1):

When you have your results you can try

```
results.totalHits;
```

if I understood you